# Does the planet Mogo have a Green Lantern ring?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

Mogo is a sentient planet and part of the Green Lantern Corps.

[image: Mogo, a sentient planet with the Green Lantern symbol painted on its surface]

But, I've always wondered, does Mogo actually possess it's own Green Lantern Ring? If it does, where is it stored? And if not, how is Mogo able to utilize the "green energy" of the Green Lanterns?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, [Mogo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mogo), like all Green Lanterns, has a Green Lantern ring.

In most incarnations, it's kept deep within the surface of the planet.  This has occasionally even been a plot point, as it is especially difficult to access or get close to Mogo's ring.  For example, in the *Green Lantern* animated series episode ["Homecoming"](https://gltas.fandom.com/wiki/Homecoming), Saint Walker is forced to take drastic action to super-charge Mogo, because his effect on most Green Lanterns is based on proximity, which isn't possible given the location of Mogo's ring.

It's worth noting that, while the ring is usually shown as being a normal-sized ring (an inch or so in diameter), Mogo is often fond of creating an enormous ring as a construct around itself. While beautiful (and utterly badass), this is *not* Mogo's actual ring.

[image: Mogo circled by a green construct looking like a Green Lantern ring]

Comment: Ok, that answers the question, but I'm still a bit curious about the specifics: You mentioned it's been a plot point before, can you reference where it's been mentioned. If it was mentioned in the animated series would you be willing to state specifically which episode?

Comment: @onewho I added a link to my answer for the episode in which Saint Walker super-charges Mogo, and I added a YouTube video showing how Mogo first got his ring in the animated series.

Comment: IIRC, in one of the comic arcs, the Sinestro Corps was attacking Mogo and were trying to drill down to his core where the ring was.

Answer (score 2):

The location of Mogo's ring changed throughout time. For instance, during the Krona arc, *Green Lantern Corps* #60 (2011) had Kyle and John reaching Mogo's brain and ring at its core. This version of the ring is quite tall:

[image: John as an Indigo Lantern and Kyle as a Blue Lantern face Mogo's ring]

After

> John destroys Mogo, and later pulls back its fragments together,

Mogo becomes the Green Lantern Corps headquarters instead of Oa. Hal finds Saint Walker in *Green Lantern* #28 (2014) and encounters Mogo's ring (this time a normal-sized ring), which Mogo keeps on its very surface for the squirrels to play with:

[image: Hal Jordan watches a treemunk playing with Mogo's ring]